# Query EF with a predicate

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, ef-core-3.1

I've got following (generic) repository method:

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, DateTime? asOf = null, IEnumerable<string> includeProperties = null,
                                    bool trackChanges = false)
{
    var query = Set.Include(includeProperties)
                   .AsOf(asOf);

    if (!trackChanges)
    {
        query = query.AsNoTracking();
    }

    return await query.SingleAsync(predicate);
}
```

When executing this test, it works fine

```
[Fact]
public static async Task GetStoffByStoffId_ReturnsEntity_OK_Test()
{
    // Arrange
    var dbContext = new SaiTestContext();
    IRepository<StoffEntity> repository = new Repository<StoffEntity>(dbContext);

    const string stoffId = "645106EF59801EE59EB22F1F93673380";

    // Act
    var entity = await repository.GetAsync(stoff => stoff.StoffId == stoffId);

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(entity);
}
```

When executing this one

```
[Fact]
public static async Task GetStoffByStoffIdPredicate_ReturnsEntity_OK_Test()
{
    // Arrange
    var dbContext = new SaiTestContext();
    IRepository<StoffEntity> repository = new Repository<StoffEntity>(dbContext);

    var stoffUpdate = new StoffUpdateEntity
                      {
                          StoffId = "645106EF59801EE59EB22F1F93673380"
                      };

    Func<StoffEntity, StoffUpdateEntity, bool> stoffSeletor =
        (stoffEntity, updateEntity) => stoffEntity.StoffId == stoffUpdate.StoffId;

    // Act
    var entity = await repository.GetAsync(stoff => stoffSeletor(stoff, stoffUpdate));

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(entity);
}
```

This exception is being thrown

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'DbSet<StoffEntity>
    .Where(s => Invoke(__stoffSeletor_0, s[StoffEntity], __stoffUpdate_1)
    )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass8_0& )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables.Query.AsOfQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables.Query.AsOfQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, LambdaExpression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.SingleAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Refdata.SAI.Data.Repositories.Repository`1.GetAsync(Expression`1 predicate, Nullable`1 asOf, IEnumerable`1 includeProperties, Boolean trackChanges) in C:\dev\Refdata.SAI\Source\Refdata.SAI.Data\Repositories\Repository.cs:line 75
   at Refdata.SAI.Data.Tests.Integration.RepositoryGetByPredicateTests.GetStoffByStoffIdPredicate_ReturnsEntity_OK_Test() in C:\dev\Refdata.SAI\Source\Refdata.SAI.Data.Tests.Integration\RepositoryGetByPredicateTests.cs:line 61
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Can the second test be fixed to work when passing the function as parameter?

The underlying reason is that I want to use this function from a generic class, where the function is being specified by `protected abstract Func<TEntity, TUpdateEntity, bool> EntitySelector { get; }` implement in the specialized classes.

Comment: I'm not a LINQ expert but what I see is that your repo wants to get a Func<T, bool> and you're creating a Func<T, T1, bool> which is not the same. So I would say you have to extend your repo method.

Comment: @user743414 No, if that was the case then there would be a compilation error, not an exception. `stoff => stoffSeletor(stoff, stoffUpdate)` is convertible to `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? EF Core classes are already generic, DbSet is already a repository. You can already use `DbSet.Find` or LINQ-to-Entities' `FindFirst` to do what you want, passing a lambda. Are you trying to create a "generic" repository on top of EF Core's repository classes?

Comment: A generic repository is an **anti**pattern when used on top of higher-level ORMs like EF Core. Oren Eini explained this in [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) as far back as 2009, and even explains why what most people end up building is a DAO, not a repository. Gunnar Peipman explains the *real* problems with generic repositories in [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) - an INSERT can end up performing 4 UPDATEs and 10 DELETEs for no reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression can be compiled to the function, but arbitrary function cannot be converted back to the expression. stoffSeletor should return expression, not a function:

```
Func<StoffUpdateEntity, Expression<Func<StoffEntity, bool>>> stoffSelector = 
    (stoffUpdate) => ((StoffEntity stoffEntity) => stoffEntity.StoffId == stoffUpdate.StoffId);
```

then

```
// create predicate expression
var predicate = stoffSelector(stoffUpdate);

// use predicate
var entity = await repository.GetAsync(predicate);
```

or short version

```
var entity = await repository.GetAsync(stoffSelector(stoffUpdate));
```

Comment: Thanks! I've also found a solution by writing an (equivalent) local function `Expression<Func<StoffEntity, bool>> StoffSelector(StoffUpdateEntity updateEntity) => stoff => stoff.StoffId == updateEntity.StoffId`

Comment: @Philippe a better solution would be to not try to re-build a generic repository on top of EF Core. A DbSet is already a repository